# Can sizeof nested twice ever be a dependent expression?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, dependent-type, compiler-bug

I noticed that gcc 5.0 rejects the following code, while clang 3.6 accepts it.

```
template<int n>
struct I
{
    typedef int Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    typedef I<sizeof(sizeof(T))>::Type Type;
};
```

The two compilers seem to differ on whether `sizeof(sizeof(T))` is a type-dependent or value-dependent expression. If the expression were dependent, then it follows that `I<sizeof(sizeof(T))>` is a dependent type, meaning that `typename` should be required.

This is covered by the following wording in the C++11 standard:

> [temp.dep.type]/8
>
> A type is dependent if it is
>
> - a simple-template-id in which either the template name is a template parameter or **any of the template
>     arguments is a dependent type or an expression that is type-dependent or value-dependent**
>
> [temp.dep.expr]/4
>
> Expressions of the following forms are never type-dependent (because the type of the expression cannot be
>   dependent):
>
> ```
> sizeof unary-expression
> sizeof ( type-id )
> ```
>
> [temp.dep.constexpr]/2
>
> Expressions of the following form are value-dependent if the unary-expression or expression is typedependent
>   or the type-id is dependent:
>
> ```
> sizeof unary-expression
> sizeof ( type-id )
> ```

My interpretation is that `sizeof(T)` can never be type-dependent, meaning `sizeof(sizeof(T))` can never be type-dependent or value-dependent.

Is this a bug in gcc?

Comment: Oh. GCC also thinks `sizeof n` is dependent. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BLobLBzkQXNRfDuq

Comment: Well, `sizeof n` is not type-dependent but value-dependent. `sizeof X`, where `X` is *not* type-dependent is not dependent at all. Hence, `sizeof sizeof n` must be nondependent, no?

Comment: Interestingly, compiles on gcc 4.7.2, but fails on 4.9.0.

Comment: @dyp Good point, I've changed the example..

Comment: @willj How does this change anything? `sizeof( type-id )` is still not type-dependent.

Comment: @dyp More parenthesis! And `sizeof n` is not value-dependent, while `sizeof(T)` is. This new version requires a second `sizeof()` to no longer be dependent.

Comment: `sizeof( type-id )` is value-dependent, but not type-dependent. `sizeof unary-expression` is dependent IFF the unary-expression is **type**-dependent. The parentheses don't change anything, it's a unaray expression with and without parentheses. (A primary expression can be a parenthesized expression.)

Comment: You have some typos in your question, swapping type and value.  In last paragraph

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using a post-N4296 draft.

```
typedef I<sizeof(sizeof(T))>::Type Type;
```

`typename` is required if the *nested-name-specifier* `I<..>` depends on a template parameter [temp.res]/5. So, is `I<..>` dependent?

> [temp.dep.type]/9 A type is dependent if it is
>
> - [...]
> - (9.7) a *simple-template-id* in which either the template name is a template parameter or any of the template arguments is a dependent
>     type or an expression that is **type-dependent** or **value-dependent**, or
>     [...]

`I<..>` is a *simple-template-id*, the template argument is an expression. Is this expression `sizeof(sizeof(T))` type-dependent or value-dependent?

The expression `sizeof(sizeof(T))` can be broken down into the following expressions:

```
expression           form
===============================================
              T      type-id
       sizeof(T)     sizeof ( type-id )
      (sizeof(T))    ( expression )
sizeof(sizeof(T))    sizeof unary-expression
```

`T` is not an expression, but I'll leave it in the list for later. A note on the parentheses: A *primary-expression* can be a parenthesized (general) *expression*. A *unary-expression* can be a *postfix-expression* which can be a *primary-expression*, hence it can be parenthesized, too.

A parenthesized expression `(X)` is dependent if `X` is dependent:

> [temp.dep.expr]/1 Except as described below, an expression is type-dependent if any subexpression is type-dependent.
>
> [temp.dep.constexpr]/1  Except as described below, a constant expression is value-dependent if any subexpression is value-dependent.

In general, `sizeof` expressions are never **type**-dependent, because they always produce a value of type `std::size_t`:

> [temp.dep.expr]/4 Expressions of the following forms **are never type-dependent** (because the type of the expression cannot be dependent):
>
> ```
> [...]
> sizeof unary-expression
> sizeof ( type-id )
> ```

However, the value they yield can be dependent on a template parameter:

> [temp.dep.constexpr]/2 Expressions of the following form **are value-dependent if the *unary-expression* or *expression* is type-dependent or the *type-id* is dependent**:
>
> ```
> sizeof unary-expression
> sizeof ( type-id )
> ```

```
expression           form                       value-dep?   type-dep?
=======================================================================
              T      type-id                    no           yes
       sizeof(T)     sizeof ( type-id )         yes          no
      (sizeof(T))    ( expression )             yes          no
sizeof(sizeof(T))    sizeof unary-expression    no           no
```

Since `T` is **type**-dependent, `sizeof(T)` becomes **value**-dependent. However, since `(sizeof(T))` is **not type**-dependent, `sizeof(sizeof(T))` is not dependent at all.

Comment: Good point on the outer set of parentheses. For some reason I'm hard-wired to write `sizeof(expression)`